# getting infinite subclass's with SetFetchMode FetchMode.Eager

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to get eagerly all level of sub objects until lasts count 0, but this returns me only first level.

in this schema I can't get loaded eagerly D and F for example;

```
A  
|_B 
| |_D
| |_F
|_C
|_E
|_G 

public class Foo
{
    public virtual int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Foo> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Parent { get; set; }
}

using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
     var CC = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Foo));
     CC.SetFetchMode("Children", FetchMode.Eager);
     return CC.List<Foo>();
}
```

Comment: *Have you considered to load the structure manually? In one shot load all FOOs and in C# (app server) iterate them and create the nesting? Have to say, that this works the best for us when moving data to UI... for tree structures (with reasonable/limited size)*

Comment: yes, I was trying to do that but just hoped there is easier way to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using Criteria, but with Linq you do it like this:

```
using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
   return session.Query<Foo>()
                 .Fetch(x => x.B)
                 .ThenFetch(x => x.D)
                 .Fetch(x => x.B)
                 .ThenFetch(x => x.F)
                 .Fetch(x => x.C)
                 .Fetch(x => x.E)
                 .Fetch(x => x.G)
                 .ToList();
}
```

But depending on how your datamodel looks like this might not be the best way performancewise.